# Is there a way to make the iTunes Store faster in Windows?

Tags: itunes, windows

I realize that iTunes is a little slow on windows in general.  But dealing with my stuff locally is workable.  But whenever I use iTunes to go the iTunes Store, that tab takes a long time to do anything.  The home page takes a couple of minutes.  I have a fast internet connection using IE or Firefox.  (Comcast 12MB service)

Any thoughts on how to make the iTunes store go faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only way to speed up iTunes is to get a faster PC or Mac. It's a bloated program with a lot of legacy code in it. It's been needing a complete overhaul for years now (even on the Mac). And as time passes, it just seems to get bigger as more is continually added.

With that said, the speed of iTunes is dependent on your Internet connection but it's also dependent on the power of your PC. Having broadband allows data to transfer quickly from Apple's servers but crunching all that data requires CPU cycles and a lot of RAM too.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated iTunes to the latest version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using DNS servers other than those of your ISP, such as Google DNS or OpenDNS? Because the iTunes Store backend uses your geographic location based on your DNS servers to speed things up, if you use DNS servers other than the ones from your ISP, it can slow things down. This mostly applies to content downloads, but I've found it can speed up the Store browser as well.

It's also worth noting that in my experience the Store browser generally feels slower than you'd expect given that it's basically glorified web pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I stumbled on the solution mentioned here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/itunes-takes-at-over-9-minutes-to-load-on-windows/4848cc42-0536-4263-a633-90824471d239

> I see you’re using the Microsoft Store version of both iTunes & iCloud. I found the same problem with the store versions so I downloaded the versions from the Apple website & these open quickly. They’re the same version as the store’s.
> I would uninstall using Revo Uninstaller>Uninstall Apps https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-u... & once completed then run the scan for leftovers then install the Apple version from here:
> https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/index.html
> http://updates-http.cdn-apple.com/2020/windows/... This is the direct link to iCloud download.